# Problems converting std::wstring to UnicodeString using "UTF8ToUnicodeString"

Tags: c++, delphi, unicode, encoding

In my project (using Embarcadero C++Builder), I am trying to convert a `std::wstring` to a `UnicodeString` using `UTF8ToUnicodeString()` from `<system.hpp>`.

The result shows some replacement characters (U+FFFD) for some Russian and Vietnamese characters. But most characters are shown correctly.

Does anybody know what the problem could be? Is it a problem with codepages?

Comment: _"...Converts a UTF-8 encoded string to a Unicode string..."_ - https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.UTF8ToUnicodeString Strange description (as UTF-8 is a Unicode encoding) and also not what you say you want to do.  Also your `std::wstring` is probably already Unicode just in the UTF-16le encoding (or UTF-32 on Linux).

Comment: Yes, the std::wstring should already be Unicode. When I write it to a file (wofstream) , everything seems to be ok. But I wanted to write that std::wstring into a cell of a Tdxspreadsheet using its method "SetText(const System::UnicodeString AText, const bool AFormulaChecking = false);". But here, the characters are shown in Ansi encoding. Using the UTF8ToUnicodeString seems to convert, but with with the problems described.

Comment: Got it. I switched from std::wstring to std::string. I don't really understand why, but it is working now.

Comment: @geldo "*I wanted to write that std::wstring into a cell of a Tdxspreadsheet using its method "SetText(const System::UnicodeString AText, const bool AFormulaChecking = false);". But here, the characters are shown in Ansi encoding*" - That is due to your misuse of `UTF8ToUnicodeString()`. You *should* be able to simply use `SetText(wstring.c_str())` without issue. "*Using the UTF8ToUnicodeString seems to convert, but with with the problems described.*" - because you should not be using `UTF8ToUnicodeString()` at all in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

First, neither `std::wstring` nor `UnicodeString` use UTF-8, so you should not be using `UTF8ToUnicodeString()` at all in this situation.  `UnicodeString` uses UTF-16 on all platforms. `std::wstring` uses UTF-16 on Windows, and UTF-32 on most other platforms.

Second, `std::wstring` is a `wchar_t`-based string. `UnicodeString` uses `wchar_t` on Windows, and `char16_t` on other platforms. It has constructors that accept C-style `wchar_t*` string pointers as input, and will convert the data to UTF-16 if needed.

So, you can simply use the `std::wstring::c_str()` method to convert `std::wstring` to `UnicodeString`, eg:

```cpp
std::wstring w = ...;
UnicodeString u = w.c_str();
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
std::wstring w = ...;
UnicodeString u(w.c_str(), w.size());
```

If you try to assign a `wchar_t*` string to a `RawByteString`, such as for the input to `UTF8ToUnicodeString()`, the RTL will perform a Unicode->ANSI conversion to the default system ANSI codepage specified by [System::DefaultSystemCodePage](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DefaultSystemCodePage), which is not universally set to UTF-8 on all platforms (especially on Windows), hence why you may lose characters, or even potentially end up with [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).